# Need regular expression to find all substring of a particular pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that may look like this:

```
IF([f1.attr_78431_]=1)  THEN(SHOWHIDE([f1.attr_78795_],[f1.attr_78641_];  [f1.attr_78795_])) 
ELSE IF([f1.attr_78431_]=2)  THEN(SHOWHIDE([f1.attr_78798_];[f1.attr_78795_], [f1.attr_78736_]))
ELSE(HIDE([f1.attr_78435_]))
```

I want to find all substrings of these patterns:

```
SHOWHIDE([f1.attr_78795_],[f1.attr_78641_];  [f1.attr_78795_])
HIDE([f1.attr_78435_])
SHOW([f1.attr_78435_],[f1.attr_78641_])
```

and ignore all other patterns like

```
IF([f1.attr_78431_]=1)
```

Do not know how to do that.

Comment: I wonder why people are voting down. I got some useful answers that look awesome and work great.

Comment: If you hover over the up/down vote buttons, you see for the downvote button "Question does not show any research effort; it is unclear and not useful". I can't tell why other people downvote, but it seems to me that the first part - no research effort - applies to your question.

Comment: because youre just asking for an answer, and have shown no evidence of actually trying to solve it yourself.

Comment: I think, it is not useful to show a horse, when you need a car. Still, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_match_all function.

```
(?:(?:SHOW)?HIDE|SHOW)\([^\)]*\)
```

Code:

```
$re = "/(?:(?:SHOW)?HIDE|SHOW)\\([^\\)]*\\)/m";
$str = "IF([f1.attr_78431_]=1) THEN(SHOWHIDE([f1.attr_78795_],[f1.attr_78641_]; [f1.attr_78795_])) \nELSE IF([f1.attr_78431_]=2) THEN(SHOWHIDE([f1.attr_78798_];[f1.attr_78795_], [f1.attr_78736_]))\nELSE(HIDE([f1.attr_78435_]))";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dH4cL3/3)

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
preg_match_all('/(?:show|hide)+\([^\)]+\)/i', $str, $matches);
```